# How to SetPrimitiveValue for core-data field swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift3

I am using NSFetchedResultsController with UITableView, and my core-data class have field *@NSManaged public var avatar_data: Data?* , and image data is getting download when cell is visible(lazy loading). when download is completed and data is set into avatar_data field. it's trigger

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?){

        }
```

I Wish to ignore any changes for avatar_data field. notification should not trigger for particular field i.e avatar_data field.

problem is it's create cycle of reload tableview. i don't have download status for image. i simply want to ignore data change notification for this field.

```
extension UIImageView{

    func downloadImageFrom(link:String, contentMode: UIViewContentMode, forContact:ContactDB, forCell:UserListTableViewCell) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask( with: NSURL(string:link)! as URL, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.contentMode =  contentMode
                if let data = data {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    forContact.avatar_thumb_data = data
                    //should not call didchange content of fetechresultcontroller
                    forContact.setPrimitiveValue(data, forKey: "avatar_thumb_data")
                    CoreDataInterface.sharedInstance.saveContext()
                    forCell.imageUserProfile?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    forCell.labelUserImage.text = ""
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

SetPrimitiveValue is applied after image download completed.

Comment: `NSManagedObject` has a `setPrimitiveValue(_:forKey:)` method. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks @TomHarrington, could you please explain it by writing code, and answer not comment.

Comment: Did you look up the method? What part of it do you not understand?

Comment: i have edited my question, it's not working.